# method for text formatting at C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

all. I'm writing a programm at C# .NET. I have a richtextBox in my form(Windows Form). I open a text file and  put text in richtextBox. I need to format selected text with FontDialog. But it's changed all text, not selected. What method can be applied, to FontDialog changed only selected text?

My code:

```
 if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
                richTextBox1.ForeColor = fontDialog1.Color;
            }
```

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - RichTextBox - Apply formatting to selected text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109032/vb-net-richtextbox-apply-formatting-to-selected-text)

Comment: thank all of you very much. It's work.))

Comment: @user3360977 You can accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the SelectionFont & SelectionColor properties of the richtextBox: because the properties you are using apply to the full contents of the control

```
if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = fontDialog1.Font;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = fontDialog1.Color;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives some good help

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = fontDialog1.Font
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = fontDialog1.Color;
```

Answer (score 0):

User RichTextBox.SelectionFont property

```
if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = fontDialog1.Font;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = fontDialog1.Color;
        }
```

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_members%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for the list of all members of RichTextBox